# Add new column into database table

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I add new columns into a table? I have a table called `Subject` and a column called `module`. Now I would like to add new columns called `question` and `answer` into the table `Subject`. Example:

Table: Subject

Module: Maths

Question: 2x2

Answer: 4

*DBHelper:*

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Voting";

// Set table name
static final String TABLE_NAME = "Subject";

// Set Table Columns
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_MODULE = "module";
static final String KEY_QUESTION = "question";
static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Category table create query
    String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_MODULE + " TEXT" + KEY_QUESTION + "TEXT" + KEY_ANSWER + "TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Inserting new Column into subjects table
 * */
public void insertColumn(String column){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_MODULE, column);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

It will be helpful if my code is updated in the answers so that I can understand easily.

Comment: check this link  http://sdroid.blogspot.in/2011/01/fixed-header-in-tablelayout.html

Comment: this link will be useful to you. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) :

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + column + " TEXT");
```

You can change the column type (TEXT) to whatever you need.

Comment: I/Database(277): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table Subject has no column named question
E/Database(277): Error inserting question=Maths
E/Database(277): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Subject has no column named question: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Subject(question) VALUES(?);

Comment: Please edit your post to show your new code, it's hard to tell what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

if you drop your table, you will lose all your data. instead of this use this;

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    if(oldVersion==1){
        db.execSQL("alter table xxx add column ....");
    }
}
```

never drop a table. or you will lose your data!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add column without loss of data you must have to alter column instead of dropping and creating new Table...

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{

    if(newVersion > oldVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("alter table table_name add column ....");
    }
}
```

Further if you want to make check and balance that if column exist you can check and then alter which help not to crash your app.... Thanks